# Can CrystalFp library be used to compare structures with different number of atoms?

Tags: crystallography, visualization-software, crystal-field, crystalfp

**Can I use [CrystalFp](http://mariovalle.name/CrystalFp/html/index.html) library to analyze different structures (e.g. of Ca2Si04) that don't have the same number of atoms?**

I want to compare e.g. structure_1 with composition [2,1,4] and structure_2 with composition [16,8,32]. Maybe both structures are the same but the second one is a supercell of the other.

I have been reading and I do not know whether CrystalFp can do this if the  structures have different compositions.